# How to find questions or answers with most votes in a specific tag?

Tags: support, tags, voting, search, sorting

How to find questions or answers with most **votes** in a specific tag? 
I think this would be very useful to find best answers or best questions.

Comment: Click on the tag, select the `voted` tab. For answers, go to the top users page, and click on `hot`; not really the most voted, but certainly the most recently highly-voted answers.

Comment: To find the questions with specific tag,
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/<your tag here>
and then click votes to sort it based on votes.

Comment: @Sibi - Didn't you read Martijn Pieters's comment or my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on any tag. Then go to `votes` tab.

Like [questions tagged sql sort by most votes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql?sort=votes)

For answers go to `top users` --> select `hot` --> select `all` to get answers list order by highest voted first.

E.g. [most voted answers tagged sql](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/hot?filter=all)

Comment: That's only questions, not answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Hmm but there is no option for that. The only relevant option is [as you suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162086/how-to-find-questions-or-answers-with-most-votes-in-a-special-tag#comment-471105)

Comment: or perhaps search, no time to figure that out right now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Is `hot` tab sort answers by votes then using `all` option may give us most voted answers list. e.g. [Most voted FAQ answers on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq/hot?filter=all)

Comment: Nice find! That could be it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the search box to do this as well, just search for your tag and the minimum number of votes you want to see, for example: `[php] votes:1` (or `[php] score:1`).  Then click the votes tab on the search results to sort that way, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20votes%3a1).

Comment: But the OP wants to find questions **or answers** with **most votes** in a specific tag (order by votes).

Comment: Oh found it. Type `[php] votes:1 is:answer` on search box and click on votes tab. We will get [the desired list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20votes%3a1%20is%3aanswer).

Comment: @hims056 - he said *or*, but yes you can restrict to either type :)